# Basic circuit analysis technique

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In the below image it is given that *R1* and *R2* is in series, how is it possible?When there is a bridge in between the two branch.After considering *R1* and *R2* as series Resistor equivalent will the middle branch disappear?
[image]

Is this below circuit simplification correct?
[image]

R equivalent from A to B is what?
[image]

Comment: $R_1$ is short circuited in this arrangement.  No current will flow through it.  It will not contribute to the total resistance of the circuit.

Comment: there is a short circuit indeed, $R_1$ does not serve to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow equipotential reduction method then you can see that the $R_1$ is short circuited. Let's understand it with the diagram below. 
[image: Initial situation]

Here I have assigned the values of the potential at the points surrounding $R_1$. Here u can see that the potential difference across $R_1$ is $0$  so no current will flow through it and u can ignore it. Thus the reduced circuit becomes

[image: Circuit after equipotential reduction]

For simplification I have assumed that a cell of emf $V$ is connected across the given circuit, u could have connected it the other way, BTW the results would have been the same. Here we also neglect any resistance in the connecting wires.

Answer (score 1):

R1 and R2 are not in series.

In fact, R1 is shorted, so no current will flow through it, and you can ignore it when analyzing the rest of the circuit.